# How can we make out that from which error, requests are getting failed during performance testing, as we are not logging request and response body?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

We are running performance test for long hours.If the transactions failed due to some issue, how to get the cause for that failure,If we log request and response body it is fine that we can make out.If we are not logging anything how can we get the cause of error.In result file we will get only reason code and description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure JMeter to log failures only by adding the next lines to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
jmeter.save.saveservice.response_data.on_error=true
```

Useful material:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Results file configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: I dont want to log the information like request and response as it will be a difference in response time.Is there any way i can assign any of my response element like transactionID to some variable and make that variable to store in the result file?

Comment: It is, extract this **transactionID** using a suitable [Post-Processor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors) and save it into `transactionID` JMeter Variable. Next add `sample_variables=transactionID` to *user.properties* file. Next time you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode_ mode the .jtl result file will have an extra column called `transactionID` holding the variable value for each request.

Comment: I know that this can be done for the request element,Can we do it for response elements as well?

Comment: Doesn't matter, it can be applied to any JMeter Variable

Comment: I am not able to save using Regular Expression Extractor.I have name spaces along with the element like <cor:SOATransactionID xmlns:cor="http://soa/coredata_1_0">26850477-9a89-4fe5-969b-4e5d5b9ca4f1</cor:SOATransactionID>. How to pick this using Regular Expression Extractor

Answer (score 0):

You may configure your listeners to store only requests with errors. Choose your listener and at the `Write results to file / Read from file` block check the `Log/Display Only: Errors`.

Also you may click `Configure` and choose information what you need to store.

Check this [JMeter capturing full output guide](https://www.redline13.com/blog/2016/02/jmeter-capturing-full-output/) for more information

Comment: I dont want to log the information like request and response as it will be a difference in response time.Is there any way i can assign any of my response element like transactionID to some variable and make that variable to store in the result file?